# How to execute a command relative to an entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how to execute a command relative to an entity in Minecraft using commands for a map I was working on. I am somewhat familiar with the use of the /execute command, but wanted to use the /summon to make a grenade using item drops or arrows, then have TNT summoned to the area that the item is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/execute` command is used to execute another command relative to something, the syntax you'll need is:

```
/execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> <command>
```

You should use [target selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_variables) with [selector arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) to select to entity you want to execute from.

To summon TNT from an item drop, you could do:

```
/execute @e[type=Item] ~ ~ ~ /summon PrimedTnt
```

**(Be careful with this command, as all item drops will act as a grenade)**

Comment: How would I do it for an item with a certain name, such as a snowball with the name "Grenade"?

Comment: @Bookmaster_VP Create a dummy objective (I'll call mine "IsGrenade" as an example), run `/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] IsGrenade 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:snowball",tag:{display:{Name:"Grenade"}}}}`, then you can target the snowball items with `@e[score_IsGrenade_min=1]`