# How do I execute a command relative to an entity in 1.15?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Already found similar posts like ([How to execute a command relative to an entity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255887/248286)), but those are some years old already and very outdated, what would be the new way to use the execute command relative (e.g. slightly behind) an entity? I'd guess it something with `at @s[z=.5]` or using the positioned tag, but neither of those worked yet. This is what I would like to accomplish, so that *only* in the right get stop the run command when they are in range, not both on the right and the left.

[image: entity and detection radius]

This is the actual detection range, where it detects the armor stand behind an infront of it.
[image: new detection range]

And this would be the new detection range, where it only stops my execute command, when theres an armor stand in front of it.
[image: New detection range]

All in all what I need is a way to reposition the anchor of the distance=0.5..1 tag, so that it's not the entity itself but rather e.g. +0.5 in the z coordinate

Comment: What am I seeing in that image? The last sentence is pretty confusing. So you want to do something behind someone, no matter how they are rotated?

Comment: I don't really know what to search for for a good duplicate target, but maybe this helps: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/362486/171580 The solution is, if I guess your question correctly, "local coordinates": https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Tilde_and_caret_notation Maybe `positioned ^ ^ ^-.5`?

Comment: I added some more pictures to show precisely what I mean. Couldn't explain it better, but I got 4 repeating command blocks for each direction n,s,w,e. That's why it doesn't matter how they are rotated. Only the anchor of the distance execution has to be repositioned slightly off.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for "local coordinates". `/execute positioned ^ ^ ^-.5` moves the execution position half a block back.

Comment: I'll try that now and see if it works! Thank you

Comment: I tried ```execute positioned ^ ^ ^-.5 as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand] unless entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,distance=0.5..1] unless block ~ ~ ~-.4 minecraft:air if block ~-.4 ~ ~.4 minecraft:carved_pumpkin[facing=north] if block ~.4 ~ ~.4 minecraft:carved_pumpkin[facing=north] run tp ~ ~ ~-.1```
but it didn't change anything. Shouldn't this work? Seems to me like I formatted something wrong, like a missing at @s

Comment: That is executed from a command block? Then you're trying to first go back 0.5 blocks from the view direction of the command block and I have no idea what that would even mean. You'll probably want something like "`/execute as <something> at @s positioned ^ ^ ^-.5 <...>`". You should also first see what this does by using a shorter command than that complex thing in your last comment.

Comment: Yeah right, what I meant was executing as the armor stand and detecting another armor stand in front of it. Tested it with the say command and it should work, but it doesn't. I don't really know why. If I remove a block, the armorstand stops teleporting because of the ```unless block ~ ~ ~-.4 minecraft:air```, but if I place it again it should start teleporting again. A single armorstand works, but as soon as I use two, they stay. That's why I thought the problem is in the ```unless entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,distance=0.5..1``` so I tried to reposition the distance detection.

Comment: The full command looks like ```execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand] at @s positioned ^ ^ ^-.5 unless entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,distance=0.5..1] unless air block ahead, if pumpkin facing north below run tp ~ ~ ~-.1```

but neither this, nor the tilde or anything else worked so far. As soon as they stop once, they keep standing still :(

Comment: "`block ahead, if pumpkin facing north below`" is part of your command? That can't work. And if you start at an armour stand, go .5 blocks in any direction and then search in a distance of .5 to 1 block, you will of course always find that armour stand, so everything after `unless entity` can never happen. Maybe add a few test cases to your question, with pictures and a list of when it should or should not do what? I think we're talking about two different things without noticing. Also, why don`t you just use tags to differentiate the armour stands? Else you'll always get confused.

Comment: I can't really come up with a good concept of using the tags, because I built a mining machine, which spawns an armor stand every second. This armor stand holds the item that the mining machine produces and i can move it by placing conveyor belts below. Those are my pumpkins. The direction they are facing determines the direction my summoned armor stands get teleported. This is the whole concept. The part your last comment started with is just the summary of what happens inside my command after the important first part which in fact still doesn't work.

Comment: I already thought about using tags, but couldn't come up with a good use of them. I thought "maybe the first armor stand gets the tag (item1) and the second (item2), the third again (item1) and so on. That way I could effectively sort out, that any armor stand counts themself into their own commands. But that is not the problem. The problem remains, that as soon as there are more than 1 armor stand queued up, they stop moving, because of ```unless entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,distance=0.5..1]```

Comment: @DasNerdwork I think I still don't understand what your project even is. I assumed you had one stationary armour stand and one moving armour stand, not many that all move. This is getting a bit long for comments, could you maybe send me a mail at fabianroeling@googlemail.com instead, please?