# How to teleport an entity behind the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm creating a Redstone contraption that involves teleporting an armour stand directly behind the player, regardless of rotation or position. I can't find anything online that helps with my problem. I've tried the following command as a rough demonstration:

`/execute at @p run tp @e[name="armourstand"] ~ ~ ~-1`

This command only teleports the armour stand one block back on the z-axis relative to the player. How do I teleport the entity directly behind the player?

A step-by-step guide would be appreciated. I'm using 1.15.2 if that helps.

Comment: Interesting, this is something that is not very well known, but also very easy to answer: Change `~` to '^'.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/367775/171580, but the system doesn't let me close it, because there is no upvoted answer. There's a meta discussion about this here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165928/353011 If anyone could please upvote my answer over there, that would be appreciated, then I can close this question.